# How to fix OpenCv android application following error in mac :

Tags: macos, opencv

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'. > Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.   Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:    https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html   or use the experimental plugin:    http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.

Comment: It looks like you have a build problem, but you don't say so. Please explain what you are doing when the error occurs.

Comment: Maybe You haven't got the NDK required for integrating `.cpp` files in Java Project, kindly look for `integrate ndk with android studio`

Comment: i wanted to use opencv library  to make a app using haarcascade c++ code.
i followed youyube tutorial and project was created in windows operating system and i am using mac and it was not clear how integrate ndk with android studio .